# Superscripts and subscripts in graphics causes italics

Tags: graphics, fonts

This is a minor problem but when putting units on graphics I sometimes get italics and sometimes not. I get italics when there are superscripts. Thus

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {" m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)\*
StyleBox[\( \!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\)]\!\(\*
StyleBox[SuperscriptBox[\"m\", \"3\"],\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 
   "m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 24}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `m` without the superscript is upright. The `m^2` is italic. In the SI system units should not be italic. In this example things are muddled

```
    Graphics[{
  Style[Text[
    "y = a +\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)]\) + \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(1\)]\) x + \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \
\(2\)]\) \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", {0, 0}], 
   FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> Times]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The font without subscripts or superscripts is upright while the font with superscripts or subscripts is italic. Even worse there seems to have been a change in font between "a" and "a subscript".

Sometimes one wants italics everywhere, sometimes nowhere. How can this be managed?  Version 11.3

**Edit**

Following helpful suggestions from Carl Woll I am now trying out using Standard form and no strings. I don't understand this as `FrameLabel` must contain a string for description as well as units.  This does not work as seen in this example

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Stress / ( N/ m^2 ) , Acceleration  / (m/s^2)}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 12}, 
 FormatType -> StandardForm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't want everything multiplied out and I want Times font.  Am I missing something here?

A better solution is

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Stress / ( N/ \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\) \
)" , "Acceleration  / (m/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the correct way to put units on plots according to the SI system except there should be no italics. The mess in StackExchange with all the backslashes is not a mess in a notebook; I guess this is a problem with the uploader.

One of the comments suggested using `FontSlant -> Plain` but this does not work :

```
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  Style[{"Stress / ( N/ \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\) )" , 
    "Acceleration  / (m/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\))"}, 
   FontSlant -> Plain], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However this does not work out either because it prevents labeling of both axes.

So I am still at a loss.

Comment: try explicitly setting `FontSlant`

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for the idea. However, I can't get it to work- see my edits

Answer (score 5):

[`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) by default uses `FormatType->TraditionalForm`, and in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) single letter *variables* are italicized. Consider:

```
{"m", m, m^2} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The string is not italicized, but the two symbols are. Your [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel) includes the string "m" as well as the *boxes* `"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \2\)]\)"`, this is why there is a mix of italic and non-italic letters.

*As an aside, there is no reason to use incomprehensible linear syntax, just use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects with expressions instead, e.g.:*

```
Row[{"m ", Superscript[m, 2]}]
```

*instead of*

```
" m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)"
```

Now, in [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm), Mathematica doesn't italicize single letters, so one possibility is to just use `FormatType->StandardForm`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {" m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)\*
StyleBox[\( \!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\)]\!\(\*
StyleBox[SuperscriptBox[\"m\", \"3\"],\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 
   "m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 24}, FormatType->StandardForm]
```

[image]

*(the $m^3$ is still italicized because you explicitly set the FontSlant)*

Another possibility is to use strings ("m") instead of symbols (m):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {" m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\"m\"\), \(2\)]\)\*
StyleBox[\( \!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\)]\!\(\*
StyleBox[SuperscriptBox[\"m\", \"3\"],\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 
   "m \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\"m\"\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 24}]
```

*(I don't include the output because it looks the same as the previous image)*.

Another possibility is to just include specific [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) wrappers to enforce `FontSlant -> Plain`.

At any rate, a good first step is stop using strings with linear syntax!

**(updated to address OP revsions)**

I said you should use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row), but you instead used [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times). At any rate, since you're interested in units, I would use the [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity) framework (this also produces the in-line fractions that you wanted):

```
Plot[
    Sin[x],
    {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{
        Row[{"Stress (", Quantity[None, "Newtons"/"Meters"^2],")"}],
        Row[{"Acceleration (", Quantity[None, "Meters"/"Seconds"^2],")"}]
    },
    BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Times", FontSize->12}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to prefer using ``SingleLetterItalics->False``

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I can't seem to get your ideas to work. Please see my edits. Also the mess with the backslashes is the result of copying using the uploader. I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What a complicated method. I guess I will make a module for `FrameLabel`. It's seems a shame that such a simple thing as labeling an axis can get so complicated. I very much appreciate your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

These are great suggestions. I am using Mathematica 12, and I find that the `Quantity` function does not always format the units properly.  In particular, when I want to express a unit with a superscript of -1, (for example $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$ for inverse seconds), the `Quantity` function gives "per second." Here is my solution (using your example).

```
Plot[
  Sin[x],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {
    Row[{"Stress (N/", Superscript["m", 2], ")"}], 
    Row[{"Acceleration (m/", Superscript["s", 2], ")"}]
  }, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}
]
```

[image: Plot generated by above code]

Note that in the example above I include the unit abbreviation as a string (in quotes) within the `Superscript` command. This keeps the unit from being italicized.

If I want, I can express the units with negative exponents.

```
Plot[
  Sin[x],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {
    Row[{"Stress (N ", Superscript["m", -2], ")"}], 
    Row[{"Acceleration (m ", Superscript["s", -2], ")"}]
  }, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}
]
```

[image: Plot generated by above code]

This gives me much more control over the format of my labels, even allowing me to use superscripts of -1 where I want.

Answer (score 0):

An example, just to summarize the main points:

```
test = Text[
    Style[#, FontSlant -> Plain, FontSize -> 32], {0, 
     0}] & /@ {Indexed[P, {i, j}], P}


Graphics /@ test
```

[image: italic]

```
Graphics[#, FormatType -> StandardForm] & /@ test
```

[image]

Thanks for the question and the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround. Namely, one can make a row like this:

```
Row[{Style["m", 24], 
  Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Placeholder]\), \(2\)]\)", 24]}]
```

and then manually remove the placeholder

```
Row[{Style["m", 24], 
  Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\), \(2\)]\)", 24]}]
```

Then the plot looks as follows:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["m", 24], 
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\), \(2\)]\)", 24]}], 
   Row[{Style["m", 24], 
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\), \(3\)]\)", 24]}]}]
```

yielding this

[image]

Have fun!